# Why does OR-Tools return me "TypeError: Not a number" on a constraint definition?

Tags: or-tools

I'm new to OR-TOOLS optimization and I'm stuck on a line of code.

In my explanation I only present the lines of code related to my problem.

In the first part of my python program, I declared my or-tools variables including these : two int variables :

```
xof = model.NewIntVar(0,1, "xof") #binary variable
duration = model.NewIntVar(1,7, "duration")
```

Other variables identical to these one (xof, duration) were also declared, since the declaration was made in a loop). Then each variable was stored in lists, then in an ordered way in a dictionary.

At the end of my code, before solver() and and the definition of the obj, I want to write loop constraints in this way for each keys list (made up of sublists):

```
for i in list_keys: #like ("100x15","80x12", "67x8")
    model.Add(sum(a*b*c for a,b,c in dic_stock_var[i])<= dic_order[i])
```

- with 'b' a fixed int value like '55',
- 'a' and 'c' or-tools variables respectively ('xor' and 'duration' );

See screenshot of 'dic_stock_var' in which these variables are stored.
[screen of dictionary composition 'dic_stock_var'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKVT.png)

And I don't understand why this line constraint in the loop gives me this error:

```
 model.Add(sum(a*b*c for a,b,c in dic_stock_var[i])<= dic_order[i])
TypeError: Not a number: duration.
```

Could you enlighten me,  thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ([AddMultiplicationEquality)](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/85fc6ef2d45d25bd4310ef9e69f24fe0057d10ad/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L1637):

```
z = model.NewIntVar(lb, ub, 'z')
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(z, xor, duration) # z = xor * duration
```

Comment: It s working thannk you !

Comment: Nice!. Maybe consider accepting the answer if it helped you!.